# Evaluating function of functions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have two symbolic functions

```
syms a(t) b(t) t
a(t) = 5*b(t);
b(t) = exp(t);
```

How do I determine the value of the function a(t=5) for a specific t, lets say t=5:

```
a(5)
```

What I get is

```
a(5)
ans = 5*b(5)
```

but I want the actual value (1.4841e+02). What I tried is something like

```
eval(a(5))
subs(a, b(t), exp(5))
```

Is there anybody who can help. Thanks!

Edit: Please note that b(t) is defined after a(t). This is important to me.

Comment: define `b(t)` first and then `a(t)`

Comment: Ask a different question, a different separate question. Also, you need to explain Why it is important to you. Else the answer is "you are wrong of giving importance to that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, most of your problems come from the order of your definitions. You create `a(t)` before defining how `b(t)` looks like, but you already have told MATLAB that `b(t)` will exists. Basically, MATLAB knows that in `a(t)` there is something called `b(t)` but doesnt really know what (as even if you have defined it, you defined it after running that line of code!).

```
syms a(t) b(t) t
a(t) = 5*b(t); % MATLAB does not error because you told it that b(t) is symbolic. It just has no idea what it looks like.
b(t) = exp(t);
```

Just change the first lines to:

```
syms a(t) b(t) t
b(t) = exp(t); % MATLAB here understand that the syntax b(t)=.. is correct, as you defined b(t) as symbolic
a(t) = 5*b(t); % MATLAB here knows what b(t) looks like, not only that it exists
```

and do

```
double(a(3))
```

To get a numeric result.

Comment: Thank you so far, unfortunately this is not possible in my actual m-file since the second function b(t) results from the first one a(t).
Does another possibility or a workaround come to your mind?

Comment: @O.Berner if your problem is actually *different* from the one you asked well.... You shoudl consider asking about the *actual* problem you have

Comment: Of course this is a mwe, but I edited the question. 
Is there a possibility of substituting b(t) in a(t) by its function, like 

    subs(a, b(t), exp(5))

but for symbolic functions?

Comment: @O.Berner if the example does not reproduce the problem, then it is a bad example. We want to teach how to properly program. That often is  telling you how not to do things, as half of the programming problems come from a bad design.